# Windows server 2012 print server Signed Driver bypass

Tags: windows-server-2012, drivers, print-server

Is there a way to bypass the requirement for signed print drivers for windows server 2012

Answer (score 1):

At boot, you should be able to hit F8 -> Advanced Boot Options -> Disable Driver Signature Enforcement.
(from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134246.aspx ~ about halfway down)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try tomorrow but I assume that 1) it will stay turned off and 2) i can turn it back on later?